# Function and process of TCTE-1 receptor

Tags: endocrinology, embryology

I was wondering if anybody knew of the **function and process** of the TCTE-1 receptor during the binding of a sperm with an egg. The only think I know of TCTE-1 is that it is a species-specific receptor.
I also know that it's removal will render homozygous males infertile. I know that researchers are experimenting with mice to study TCTE-1.

Answer (score 1):

This is by far too long for a comment, so as an answer: I spend now quite a while using Pubmed and other search tools, to find more information. The most recent article I found over and over again was the one from Juneja and colleagues: "[Sequence divergence within the sperm-specific polypeptide TCTE1 is correlated with species-specific differences in sperm binding to zona-intact eggs.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9570741)" (which you probably also found). This article has only been cited two times, which is a bad sign for an article making so important connections. My guess is that no further research in this area either happened or has at least not been published. So beyond this I am afraid that there is no other information available (I am happy to change this, if there is any other information available).